# Want to write from os.Stdin to os.Stdout using channels

Tags: go, channel

```
/* Want to write from os.Stdin to os.Stdout(fmt.Println() in below code) using channels*/
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "bufio"
)

type message []byte
/* Function to run the groutine to run for stdin read */
func read (r io.Reader) <-chan message{
    lines := make (chan message)
    go func() {
        defer close(lines)
        scan := bufio.NewScanner(r)
        for scan.Scan() {
            lines <- message(scan.Bytes())
        }   
    }() 
    return lines
}


func main() {
    mes := make (chan message, 1)
    sig := make (chan bool)
    ch := read (os.Stdin) //Reading from Stdin
    for {
        select {
            case anu := <-mes:
                fmt.Println("Message to stdout")
                fmt.Println(string(anu)) //Writing to Stdout
            case mes <- <-ch:
                fmt.Println("Message to channel 2")
                continue
        }   
    }   
    <-sig

/*
The O/P is :

go run writetochan.go 
Golang
Message to channel 2
Fun     <<< Delayed O/P golang means after putting one more 
            message only we are getting First message
Message to stdout
Golang


Expected O/P:
go run writetochan.go 
Golang
Message to channel 2
Message to stdout
Golang
Fun
Message to channel 2

*/
}
```

Want to achieve the O/P shown above.

We are writing from one channel which reads all the stdin from the user and then writes to the stdout. Channel read is happening in goroutine. A dummy channel is formed (sig) so that we can run it indefinitely (Just for now).

Comment: I guess this is homework?

Comment: You can't share the slice used by a bufio.Scanner -- from the docs: `The underlying array may point to data that will be overwritten by a subsequent call to Scan`

Comment: please use `gofmt`. I know go gets quite a bit of criticism for being overly opinionated WRT coding style, but the way your code looks makes it harder to read for ppl who have become used to the golang standard formatting. The extra space in statements like ` sig := make (chan bool)` and the extra level of indentation for your `select-case` blocks shouldn't be there

Comment: @JimB: I stand corrected, it is possible to lose data, but the race detector doesn't seem to pick up on. I ran a small test reading from stdin (input 1, 2, 3, ...), and got output 1, 5, 6, 8, 9. Clearly a race condition, but `go run -race foo.go` didn't give a peep...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Just because the output is logically incorrect doesn't mean the reads and writes happened concurrently -- the race detector can only detect when a race actually happens. For the same reason you initially thought there wasn't a race, this doesn't leave a very large window for it to happen. I just tested it out on some archives in the 100s of Mb and get only 1 or 2 data races per file.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest the code snippet for the expected output.... where we will read from stdin in one goroutine and write on stdout using fmt.Println....the communication among goroutine should happen via channels... as intended in the code...

Comment: @JimB for sure, race conditions are tricky to detect automatically. We've all wasted too much time debugging code like this. My thinking was simply this: blocking write to an unbuffered channel, read + copy to a buffered one. My mistake was for me to think that the copy would've been atomic. Clearly it isn't. Honest mistake on my part, but a mistake nonetheless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have two channel operations in your second `select` case.  Select only prevents the *outer* operation from blocking.  Thus the `<-ch` call is evaluated immediately, and doesn't have the blocking protection of the select, so the entire select statement blocks until something else is received on that channel (which requires another input so `read()` can send again on that channel).

Unfortunately, the fix isn't as clean.  If you change it to `case m := <-ch:`, then sending `m` over `mes` will block the select, and can result in a deadlock if it's already at buffer.  Probably the easiest way to fix it is to only have a single channel, rather than two.  Example:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

/* Function to run the groutine to run for stdin read */
func read(r io.Reader) <-chan string {
    lines := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        defer close(lines)
        scan := bufio.NewScanner(r)
        for scan.Scan() {
            lines <- scan.Text()
        }
    }()
    return lines
}

func main() {
    mes := read(os.Stdin) //Reading from Stdin
    for anu := range mes {
        fmt.Println("Message to stdout")
        fmt.Println(anu) //Writing to Stdout
    }
}
```

Note that I changed your `scan.Bytes()` call to `scan.Text()`, because the comments for `scan.Bytes()` specifically state that the underlying array of the slice it returns is not safe against being overwritten by following Scan calls.

Another alternative is to use a separate goroutine to translate the messages between the channels:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

/* Function to run the groutine to run for stdin read */
func read(r io.Reader) <-chan string {
    lines := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        defer close(lines)
        scan := bufio.NewScanner(r)
        for scan.Scan() {
            s := scan.Text()
            lines <- s
        }
    }()
    return lines
}

func main() {
    mes := make(chan string, 1)
    ch := read(os.Stdin) //Reading from Stdin
    go func() {
        for m := range ch {
            fmt.Println("Message to channel 2")
            mes <- m
        }
    }()
    for anu := range mes {
        fmt.Println("Message to stdout")
        fmt.Println(anu) //Writing to Stdout
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realized the mistake with the usage of select.